# ¿No consigo imprimir un String que paso a una función que lo vuelve del revés?, esta es mi última configuración, pero tampoco, alguna orientación?

Tags: c, punteros

Este es el código propuesto, he cambiado de manejar punteros del modo str++ a declarar arrays, para poder manipular los contenidos, con diferentes resultados, pero siempre con errores al ejecutar (bus error o segmentation fault). La última opción probada es con la función malloc() e intentar que el resultado no se altere, pero tampoco. Os muestro el código por si podeis orientarme. La idea es pasarle un string a una función y que esta me devuelva el string al revés. He utilizado VSCode pero no he conseguido en la depuración saber donde se produce el error. Actualmente la salida no se corresponde con el string apuntado. Saludos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char    *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
int     count;
int     i;
char    c;
char    aux[20];

count = 0;
while (str[count] != '\0')
    count++;
count = count - 1;
i = 0;
while (i < ((count + 1) / 2))
{
    c = str[i];
    aux[i] = str[count - i];
    aux[count - i] = c;
    i++;
}
aux[i+1] = '\0';
str = &(aux[0]);
return (str);
}

int main(void)
{
char    *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);

str = ft_strrev("Es");
printf("%s\n", str);
free(str);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Restarle uno a `count` está demás. El carácter nulo solo sirve para indicar que el string terminó. Por lo tanto no debes tenerlo en cuenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solamente viendo estas dos líneas ya se aprecian dos problemas en el código: pierde memoria.

```
char    *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
str = ft_strrev("Es");
```

La función no recibe el puntero `str` en ningún momento y, sin embargo, si que lo modifica, luego la memoria reservada por `malloc` se pierde irremediablemente.

`str` no es más que un puntero, es decir, es una variable que en vez de almacenar números almacena direcciones de memoria. Lo que hace una asignación no es modificar la dirección almacenada en dicho puntero, con lo que el puntero pasará a apuntar a otra región de memoria diferente.

Si esto no sucediese (que la memoria no se perdiese) el programa tampoco funcionaría proque la reserva que has hecho es claramente insuficiente. Para almacenar 2 caracteres en un string necesitas que el mismo tenga capacidad para, al menos 3 caracteres. Nunca hay que olvidar que los strings terminan con el caracter nulo, luego dicho caracter, aunque no "se vea", sigue formando parte de la cadena y hay que reservarle un hueco.

Revisando la función `ft_strrev` ya encontramos otro error grave:

```
char    *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
    char    aux[20];

    str = &(aux[0]);
    return (str);
}
```

La función devuelve un puntero a un array que es local a la función. `aux` solo  *existe* mientras se está ejecutando `ft_strrev`. Cuando la ejecución abandona la función, la memoria asociada a `aux` se libera y puede ser utilizada con otros fines.

No puedes devolver la dirección de memoria de una variable local. **NUNCA**

Lo que tienes que hacer es reservar memoria **dentro** de `ft_strrev`:

```
char * ft_strrev(char const* str)
{
    char* to_return = (char*)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    return to_return;
}
```

Ahora ya no se está devolviendo la dirección de memoria de una variable local (stack) sino que `to_return` apunta al *heap* (memoria dinámica) del programa. La memoria dinámica tiene que ser gestionada por nosotros de forma manual, luego somos los que decidimos cuándo dicha memoria se libera y, por extensión, cuando no.

Invertir la cadena ahora no es más que un proceso iterativo: Se recorre `str` y se va copiando cada caracter de dicha cadena en la posición que le corresponda en `to_return`:

```
int length = strlen(str);
char* to_return = (char*)malloc(length + 1) * sizeof(char));

for (char* orig = str, * dest = to_return + length - 1; *orig; ++orig, --dest)
    *dest = *orig;

to_return[length] = '\0';

return to_return;
```

Comment: lo primero muchas gracias y funciona, pero me surgen problemas al liberar la memoria con free() desde main(), variable no declarada o variable no inicializada, como la longitud no la conozco hasta que llamo a la función ft_strrev(), este es el código final.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código final gracias a los comentarios de @eferion, quedan por resolver algunos flecos, como liberar memoria con free(), que el compilador detecta como error. Esta versión del código evita los errores anteriores de 'bus error' y 'Segmentation fault', al utilizar la reserva de memoria a través de la función malloc() y posicionar los punteros en *orig y *dest debidamente para realizar la escritura al revés (objeto de este código), mediante iteración.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_strlen(char *str)
{   
int length;

length = 0;
while (str[length] != '\0')
    length++;
return (length);
}

char    *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
int length = ft_strlen(str);
char    *to_return = (char*) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));

for (char* orig = str, *dest = to_return + length - 1; *orig; ++orig, --dest)
    *dest = *orig;
to_return[length] = '\0';
return (to_return);
}

int main(void)
{
char *text;
char *to_return;
text = ft_strrev("Esto");
printf("%s\n", text);
free(to_return);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Si la respuesta de @efeiron te ha ayudado a resolver tu pregunta y recodificar tu código tal como lo estas mostrando ahora, deberias aceptarla. Léete el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio, y descubrir porque es importante aceptar respuestas válidas.  Esta respuesta que has puesto, si bien dices te funciona, no está explicada, y eso hace que esté catalogada como de baja calidad porque dificilmente ayudará a comprenderla a nadie que tenga el mismo problema. Léete [answer]. Gracias.

Comment: En `main` tienes que invocar `free(text)`, pues el puntero que ha devuelto `ft_strrev` lo has almacendo en `text`. La variable `to_return` del main es independiente de la variable `to_return` de `ft_strlen`, es como cuando dos personas tienen el mismo nombre, siguen siendo personas diferentes. Si en `main` haces la asignación sobre `text`, entonces tienes que usar `text`. Por mucho que declares `to_return`, esa variable no va a heredar mágicamente los valores que tiene su homónima en `ft_strlen`

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy empezando a comprender y tus consejos sobre este código me están ayudando mucho